# Angular JS - Dynamically loaded model for textarea, not rendering curly bracket variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am building a rails application and am using some AngularJS on the front end.

The Goal: To edit a dynamically loaded description template, with areas of the template being changed based on other inputs being filled out.

For example the `$scope.description` is: `"This {{productName}} is really great. It also has {{subtitle}}, and some more words."`

However, when I load the template to the description model, it does not render the curly bracket wrapped variables inside the description model.

It is being rendered exactly how you see it above, and instead of replacing the curly bracket variables with their corresponding `$scope` variable values.

For example, I want the description to look like this: `"This test product is really great. It also has test subtitle and some more words."`

See this example image:
[image: Example image]

Here's some code:

```
// From AngularJS Controller

$scope.productName = "test product";
$scope.subtitle = "test subtitle";

$scope.description = $(".entertainmentTemplate").data("template");

//In the view template description is stored as data because it is set dynamically
- @active_templates.each do |template|
            %li
                %a{ remote: true, data: {template: "#{template.description}"}}= template.name

// View of the input fields 
= f.text_field :subtitle, "ng-model" => "productName"
= f.text_field :subtitle, "ng-model" => "subtitle"

// Description view
= f.text_area :description, "ng-model" => "description"
```

Please let me know if I need to include any more context.

Comment: you shouldn't use jquery with angular, anything happening in jquery is outside of Angular's event cycle. so anything that changes requires a manually called digest.

Comment: @alphapilgrim Thanks for replying. I tried removing the jquery by just using vanilla js like so `$scope.description =  document.getElementsByClassName("entertainmentTemplate")[0].dataset.template`  Although I am seeing the same issues. Were you referring to something else?

Comment: you probably need to compile it manually before it gets rendered , try to use $compile

Comment: If your template is coming in a response then you'll need to $compile it like Panos said.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have never used `$compile`, I just did some research on it, but can't seem to figure out how to use it in this case. Could you provide a relevant example of how `$compile` could help here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The solution was the service `$interpolate`

`$interpolate` will replace all unrendered instance of {{expression variables}} in the assigned controller scope.

Here's the updated code:

```
// From AngularJS Controller

$scope.productName = "test product";
$scope.subtitle = "test subtitle";

// I used the gon gem to store the value from the rails controller then 
passed it to the JS like so:

$scope.entertainmentTemplate = gon.active_entertainment_template.descripti

// Interpolate the variable with the controller $scope as the scope and 
assign it to the model you wish.

$scope.description = $interpolate($scope.entertainmentTemplate)($scope);

// View of the input fields 
= f.text_field :subtitle, "ng-model" => "productName"
= f.text_field :subtitle, "ng-model" => "subtitle"

// Description view
= f.text_area :description, "ng-model" => "description"
```

Make sure you add the `$interpolate` service to the controller like so:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('listingFormCtrl',['$scope', '$interpolate', function($scope, $interpolate) {

}]);
```